# Trying to get my python loop to run for a specific amount of iterstions entered by the user

Tags: python-2.7

I am fairly new to python and was wondering how to make this loop run for a the number of iterations that is entered by the user, however it is an infinite loop at the moment:

```
def randMod():
   import random
   heads = 0
   tails = 0
   tries = raw_input('Enter a number:')

   while True:
       runs = 0
       if tries == runs:
           break
       else:
           runs + 1


       coinFlip = random.randrange(0,1+1)

       if coinFlip == 0:
           print "Tails"
           tails + 1

       elif coinFlip == 1:
           print "Heads"
           heads + 1

       print heads
       print tails

randMod()
```

I am trying to make it so it will simulate a coin flip for how many times the user enters then tallies it at the end. Only problem is I am fairly new to python so I don't know if I got this right or not.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see here is that you are using `raw_input()` to read the user's input. That method stores the input as a string. You must convert the information contained in `tries` to a number in order for this to work. As it is comparing `tries == runs` and a string will never be equal to a int, it is stuck forever.

You can use the conversion like this:
[Explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/parse-string-to-float-or-int)

Comment: Minor nitpick: it's not casting (re-interpreting a value as a different type) it's conversion (taking a value of one type and creating a value of another type)